# How can I make a function that adds a number to each value in an array?

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I am new to F# and I am trying to make a function called sumUp that adds 2 values like 1+2.
But I want it to work on an array, I tried the code you see in the snippit, but it doesnt seem to work, what am I doing wrong and why isn't this working?

```
let sumUp int1 int2 = int1 + int2

let numbers = [1;2;3]

numbers |> Seq.map (sumUp 4)
```

my expected result is [5,6,7] but i dont get any result at all.

This is my output:

```
- let sumUp int1 int2 = int1 + int2
-
- let numbers = [1;2;3]
-
- let result = numbers |> Seq.map (sumUp 4)
- ;;
val sumUp: int1: int -> int2: int -> int
val numbers: int list = [1; 2; 3]
val result: seq<int>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean by "no result at all". Could you please post the output of whatever you're doing to get the result?

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong to get the result, because it doesnt show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct. The only problem is that `Seq.map` is a lazy function, so the value of `result` is just `seq<int>` until you do something to enumerate the sequence. You can do this using `printfn`, for example:

```ml
> let result = numbers |> Seq.map (sumUp 4);;
val result: seq<int>

> printfn "%A" result;;
seq [5; 6; 7]
```

Alternatively, you could use `List.map` instead of `Seq.map` to avoid lazy evaluation in the first place:

```ml
> let result = numbers |> List.map (sumUp 4);;
val result: int list = [5; 6; 7]
```

Note that your input (`[1;2;3]`) is a list, not an array. If you want to use arrays instead, try this:

```ml
> let numbers = [|1;2;3|];;
val numbers: int[] = [|1; 2; 3|]

> let result = numbers |> Array.map (sumUp 4);;
val result: int[] = [|5; 6; 7|]
```